# Directions API, > stops with Custom Icons sequenced

Tags: java, markers, directions

I am a novice with Java so forgive me but using the google API i want to create a map with > 8  waypoints and custom numbered icons going up in sequence. I can create custom icons going up in sequence and also a map with > 8 waypoints but i am struggling to combine. Code below for showing > 8 Waypoint, this is not my code i got it elsewhere from a demo and slightly adapted it. 
Many Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Directions Waypoints</title>
<style>
    #map{
    width: 86%;
    height: 489px;
}
</style>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?"></script>
    <script>



      jQuery(function() {




    var stops =  (function() {
        var json = null;
        $.ajax({
            'async': false,
            'global': false,
            'url': "/routes.txt",
            'dataType': "json",
            'success': function (data) {
                json = data;
            }
        });
        return json;
    })()





    var map = new window.google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"));

    // new up complex objects before passing them around
    var directionsDisplay = new window.google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({suppressMarkers: true});
    var directionsService = new window.google.maps.DirectionsService();

    Tour_startUp(stops);

    window.tour.loadMap(map, directionsDisplay);
    window.tour.fitBounds(map);

    if (stops.length > 1)
        window.tour.calcRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);
});
function Tour_startUp(stops) {
    if (!window.tour) window.tour = {
        updateStops: function (newStops) {
            stops = newStops;
        },
        // map: google map object
        // directionsDisplay: google directionsDisplay object (comes in empty)
        loadMap: function (map, directionsDisplay) {
            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 13,
                center: new window.google.maps.LatLng(51.507937, -0.076188), // default to London
                mapTypeId: window.google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            map.setOptions(myOptions);
            directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
        },
        fitBounds: function (map) {
            var bounds = new window.google.maps.LatLngBounds();

            // extend bounds for each record
            jQuery.each(stops, function (key, val) {
                var myLatlng = new window.google.maps.LatLng(val.Geometry.Latitude, val.Geometry.Longitude);
                bounds.extend(myLatlng);
            });
            map.fitBounds(bounds);
        },
        calcRoute: function (directionsService, directionsDisplay) {
            var batches = [];
            var itemsPerBatch = 10; // google API max = 10 - 1 start, 1 stop, and 8 waypoints
            var itemsCounter = 0;
            var wayptsExist = stops.length > 0;

            while (wayptsExist) {
                var subBatch = [];
                var subitemsCounter = 0;

                for (var j = itemsCounter; j < stops.length; j++) {
                    subitemsCounter++;
                    subBatch.push({
                        location: new window.google.maps.LatLng(stops[j].Geometry.Latitude, stops[j].Geometry.Longitude),
                        stopover: true
                    });
                    if (subitemsCounter == itemsPerBatch)
                        break;
                }

                itemsCounter += subitemsCounter;
                batches.push(subBatch);
                wayptsExist = itemsCounter < stops.length;
                // If it runs again there are still points. Minus 1 before continuing to
                // start up with end of previous tour leg
                itemsCounter--;
            }

            // now we should have a 2 dimensional array with a list of a list of waypoints
            var combinedResults;
            var unsortedResults = [{}]; // to hold the counter and the results themselves as they come back, to later sort
            var directionsResultsReturned = 0;

            for (var k = 0; k < batches.length; k++) {
                var lastIndex = batches[k].length - 1;
                var start = batches[k][0].location;
                var end = batches[k][lastIndex].location;

                // trim first and last entry from array
                var waypts = [];
                waypts = batches[k];
                waypts.splice(0, 1);
                waypts.splice(waypts.length - 1, 1);

                var request = {
                    origin: start,
                    destination: end,
                    waypoints: waypts,
                    travelMode: window.google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
                };
                (function (kk) {
                    directionsService.route(request, function (result, status) {
                        if (status == window.google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {

                            var unsortedResult = { order: kk, result: result };
                            unsortedResults.push(unsortedResult);

                            directionsResultsReturned++;

                            if (directionsResultsReturned == batches.length) // we've received all the results. put to map
                            {
                                // sort the returned values into their correct order
                                unsortedResults.sort(function (a, b) { return parseFloat(a.order) - parseFloat(b.order); });
                                var count = 0;
                                for (var key in unsortedResults) {
                                    if (unsortedResults[key].result != null) {
                                        if (unsortedResults.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                                            if (count == 0) // first results. new up the combinedResults object
                                                combinedResults = unsortedResults[key].result;
                                            else {
                                                // only building up legs, overview_path, and bounds in my consolidated object. This is not a complete
                                                // directionResults object, but enough to draw a path on the map, which is all I need
                                                combinedResults.routes[0].legs = combinedResults.routes[0].legs.concat(unsortedResults[key].result.routes[0].legs);
                                                combinedResults.routes[0].overview_path = combinedResults.routes[0].overview_path.concat(unsortedResults[key].result.routes[0].overview_path);

                                                combinedResults.routes[0].bounds = combinedResults.routes[0].bounds.extend(unsortedResults[key].result.routes[0].bounds.getNorthEast());
                                                combinedResults.routes[0].bounds = combinedResults.routes[0].bounds.extend(unsortedResults[key].result.routes[0].bounds.getSouthWest());
                                            }
                                            count++;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                directionsDisplay.setDirections(combinedResults);
                                var legs = combinedResults.routes[0].legs;
                                // alert(legs.length);
                                for (var i=0; i < legs.length;i++){
                  var markerletter = "A".charCodeAt(0);
                  markerletter += i;
                                  markerletter = String.fromCharCode(markerletter);
                                  createMarker(directionsDisplay.getMap(),legs[i].start_location,"marker"+i,"Drop#"+i+"<br>"+legs[i].start_address,markerletter);
                                }
                                var i=legs.length;
                                var markerletter = "A".charCodeAt(0);
                    markerletter += i;
                                markerletter = String.fromCharCode(markerletter);
                                createMarker(directionsDisplay.getMap(),legs[legs.length-1].end_location,"marker"+i,"some text for the "+i+"marker<br>"+legs[legs.length-1].end_address,markerletter);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                })(k);
            }
        }
    };
}
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
  { 
    size: new google.maps.Size(150,50)
  });

var icons = new Array();
icons["red"] = new google.maps.MarkerImage("mapIcons/marker_red.png",
      // This marker is 20 pixels wide by 34 pixels tall.
      new google.maps.Size(20, 34),
      // The origin for this image is 0,0.
      new google.maps.Point(0,0),
      // The anchor for this image is at 9,34.
      new google.maps.Point(9, 34));



function getMarkerImage(iconStr) {
   if ((typeof(iconStr)=="undefined") || (iconStr==null)) { 
      iconStr = "red"; 
   }
   if (!icons[iconStr]) {
      icons[iconStr] = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://www.google.com/mapfiles/marker"+ iconStr +".png",
      // This marker is 20 pixels wide by 34 pixels tall.
      new google.maps.Size(20, 34),
      // The origin for this image is 0,0.
      new google.maps.Point(0,0),
      // The anchor for this image is at 6,20.
      new google.maps.Point(9, 34));
   } 
   return icons[iconStr];

}
  // Marker sizes are expressed as a Size of X,Y
  // where the origin of the image (0,0) is located
  // in the top left of the image.

  // Origins, anchor positions and coordinates of the marker
  // increase in the X direction to the right and in
  // the Y direction down.

  var iconImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage('mapIcons/marker_red.png',
      // This marker is 20 pixels wide by 34 pixels tall.
      new google.maps.Size(20, 34),
      // The origin for this image is 0,0.
      new google.maps.Point(0,0),
      // The anchor for this image is at 9,34.
      new google.maps.Point(9, 34));
  var iconShadow = new google.maps.MarkerImage('http://www.google.com/mapfiles/shadow50.png',
      // The shadow image is larger in the horizontal dimension
      // while the position and offset are the same as for the main image.
      new google.maps.Size(37, 34),
      new google.maps.Point(0,0),
      new google.maps.Point(9, 34));
      // Shapes define the clickable region of the icon.
      // The type defines an HTML &lt;area&gt; element 'poly' which
      // traces out a polygon as a series of X,Y points. The final
      // coordinate closes the poly by connecting to the first
      // coordinate.
  var iconShape = {
      coord: [9,0,6,1,4,2,2,4,0,8,0,12,1,14,2,16,5,19,7,23,8,26,9,30,9,34,11,34,11,30,12,26,13,24,14,21,16,18,18,16,20,12,20,8,18,4,16,2,15,1,13,0],
      type: 'poly'
  };


function createMarker(map, latlng, label, html, color) {
// alert("createMarker("+latlng+","+label+","+html+","+color+")");
    var contentString = '<b>'+label+'</b><br>'+html;
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        map: map,
        shadow: iconShadow,
        icon: getMarkerImage(color),
        shape: iconShape,
        title: label,
        zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat()*-100000)<<5
        });
        marker.myname = label;

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.setContent(contentString); 
        infowindow.open(map,marker);
        });
    return marker;
}
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="map"></div>
<script src="http://www.google-analytics.com/urchin.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
_uacct = "UA-162157-1";
urchinTracker();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```